# what are the get prop and set prop methods in ember objects?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In every ember object i see functions for every computed property like this

```
get name: function () { ... }
set name: function (value) { ... }
```

What are they, they seem pointless to me, and as for the space....
Is this even a function (with a space)?

Any explanations?

**SCREENSHOT**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

These are `getters` and `setters`.
Reference: [MDN — Defining getters and setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters)

Ember.js uses them heavily to implement the observer pattern.

---

```
function (value) { // ...
```

The above line is an anonymous function declaration.
Reference: [MDN — Function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Function_constructor_vs._function_declaration_vs._function_expression)

Comment: @connor.js I've updated my answer. This is an anonymous function.

Answer (score 2):

The `get` and `set` methods on `Ember.Object` are used to observers, which in turn are used for computed properties. It might seem weird at first, but without it Ember wouldn't know when you changed a property on one of your objects.  Ember coalesces these object changes in the run loop and applies them in bulk to the DOM.

The `get/set` stuff is probably one of the most polarizing aspects of Ember's API.